# Simple Image Hosting for hundreds-thousands of images (5-10GB) which preserves file names

Tags: javascript, web-development, html, web-services, hosted

I am developing an online experiment on Heroku that involves hundreds to thousands of images. Heroku has a 1GB limit, so I need to use another host for the images. I expect to have 5-10GB of images, and each image is a 600 by 700 png.

At first I considered imgbox, which seems like a good candidate in every way except I don't know how my code would know where to look for specific images. My images themselves are organized by file name but imgbox gives each image a url with a random generated key. This would be fine for a few images but not for hundreds to thousands.

So basically, I just need something like imgbox which I can directly load via html/javascript into my public site without CORS issues, but where the image urls are a constant gallery prefix + the original filename of the individual images as opposed to some random generated key.

While free is of course always best, I am able to pay if required.

Comment: Don't know if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810995/image-hosting-azure#24811078

Comment: [backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Wolfram Cloud, which has 15GB free at my institution.